# Recommendation for Torah Reader's "guide"

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-reading

As a long-time *Ba'al Kri'ah* (Torah reader), I am looking for ways to refine my skill. I realize that there are numerous specifics involved in reading, such as the following:

- Places where a change of accent from the 1st to the last syllable or vice versa changes the meaning of the word. (*mil'el* vs. *milra*)
- Use of the *nosav achor* rule - e.g. a word which is usually accented on the last syllable will have its accent shift back one syllable if the following word is a 1-syllable word. This is done to avoid having to consecutive accented syllables.
- Places where the wrong trope (cantillation) changes the meaning of the verse. (One of the purposes of trope notes is for syntax.)

I think there is a book around that goes through each parsha (weekly Torah reading) and outlines all the "anomalies" or places within each parsha where the Torah reader should pay attention. I don't recall what this book is. Can someone recommend or locate this and know if I can find this book in any Judaica store or order online?

BTW - While I hope to peruse this myself, I hope to train 1 or 2 gabba'im on this as well. In general, I think few gabba'im are aware of these nuances, and they should be educated!

Comment: A baal keriah should get all the accents and tropes right even when it doesn't change the meaning. Are you looking for a guide for a gabbai/magiah/correcter?

Comment: @DoubleAA It's meant to serve a dual purpose. Your 1st sentence is obvious to me, and I wasn't trying to imply, otherwise. As stated in my 1st sentence, I'm trying to perfect my skill and knowledge, so I want to be aware, myself, of the "critical" points. This way, I can train a "corrector". I'm unfamiliar with the term *magi'ah* as used, here. What does it mean?